# Find 2nd and 3rd level connections in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, recursive-query

I have a `connections` table that maps connections between 2 users using user_id.

```
create table connections (id serial primary key,user1 int, user2 int);

insert into connections  (user1, user2)
values
    (1,2),(1,3),(1,4),
    (2,3),(2,5),
    (3,6)
;
```

I would like to get 2nd and 3rd level connections for `user_id=1`.

```
-- 1st level connections
select user1 from connections where user2=1
union 
select user2 from connections where user1=1
```

Any suggestion in table structure change is also welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CTE to generate the first level matches, then `union all` and join it to get the second level:

```
with c1 as (
    select case when user1 = 1 then user2 else user1 end usr
    from connections c
    where 1 in (user1, user2)
)
select usr, 1 lvl from c1
union all 
select case when c2.user1 = c1.usr then c2.user2 else c2.user1 end usr, 2 lvl
from c1
inner join connections c2 
    on (c1.usr = c2.user1 and c2.user2 <> 1)
    or (c1.usr = c2.user2 and c2.user1 <> 1)
order by lvl, usr
```

Answer (score 0):

1st and 2nd level connections:

```
with c1 as (
    select user1 from connections where user2=1
    union 
    select user2 from connections where user1=1
)
select *,1 as conn_level from c1 
union 
select user1,2 from connections where user2 in (select * from c1) 
    and user1 not in (select * from c1) and user1<>1
union 
select user2,2 from connections where user1 in (select * from c1) 
    and user2 not in (select * from c1) and user2<>1
order by conn_level;
```

But hoping to find a better way to do this.